# Condition to check if any element of an array has a certain values in bash

Tags: bash

I have two bash array containing a few strings with the names of some files and their directories, and I have a directory that contains those files. I want to create a condition that is true when the array of strings contains files from that directory, with the exception of two files.

Example:
I have a directory `dir` with 5 files: file1, file2, file3, file1-suffix and file2-suffix.
And I have this array of strings:

```
files=("dir/file1" "dir/file2" "dir/file1-suffix" "anotherdir/file")
directories=$("dir" "anotherdir")
```

I want to create a condition that is true if the array contains any of the elements that do not have the "-suffix" suffix (in the above example file1, file2 and file3). In the real case the number of files is arbitrarily large, so I can't do an If statement for each file.

Since they all share the same directory, I could check that, but then the condition would be true for the -suffix files and I don't care about those.

Right now my condition looks like this

```
if ( [[ " ${directories[*]} " =~ " ${DIRECTORY} " ]] && ! [[ " ${files[*]} " =~ '-suffix' ]] )
```

However, in the case where my `files` array contains both suffix and nonsuffix files, this condition is evaluated as false, and I want it to be true in that case.

So, to sum up, I would like to obtain the following behavior in an "elegant" way:

```
files=("dir/file1" "dir/file2")
```

The condition is true.

```
files=("dir/file1" "dir/file1-suffix")
```

The condition is true.

```
files=("dir/file1-suffix" "dir/file2-suffix")
```

The condition is false.

```
files=("anotherdir/file1" "anotherdir/file2")
```

The condition is false.

I've also considered moving all the suffix files to a different directory, but I would prefer to avoid that option if possible. The question is a little bit tricky so sorry if I didn't make myself clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why is the `anotherdir` item not included in the desired results? (As an aside, `$(` is completely wrong here, you probably mean simply `(`.)

Comment: `then the condition would be true for the -suffix files` soooo remove from the array the elements with `-suffix`? `all the suffix files` wait, you have files __or__ you have two bash arrays? `in an "elegant" way:` Why "elegant"? Just write the loop, that iterates over one array, then for each element of another checks if they are equal, excluding the one with `-suffix`. I do not understand. How would _you_ check if the condition is true on paper, by hand?

Comment: `files=$("dir/file1" "dir/file2")` is just wrong. It is process substitution, not array assignment. You want `files=("dir/file1" "dir/file2")` (no `$`).

Comment: Edit with the $() fix. Thanks.

Comment: Still `directories=$("dir" "anotherdir")` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow your logic correctly, you want to check whether the array is nonempty after removing any entries which are not in `$DIRECTORY` and any entries which match `-suffix`.

```
matched=()
for item in "${files[@]}"; do
    case $item in
     *-suffix) continue;;
     "$DIRECTORY"/*) ;;
     *) continue;;
    esac
    # If you reach here, the condition is true already
    matched+=("$item")
done
```

The loop collects the matching files in `matched`; you could check after the loop if the intersection contains any elements, but if all you care about is whether there is at least one file in the set, you could `break` out of the loop and return true as soon as you get past the `esac`.

Notice how we take care to properly quote any array items. Your use of `"${files[*]}"` would blindly consider a file named `"otherdir or dir/file"` as being in `dir` which obviously isn't true at all.

Using an array is completely unnecessary and slightly wasteful if you just want to check whether a directory contains matches. Just loop over the files in the directory directly then.

```
for file in "$DIRECTORY"/*; do
    case $file in *-suffix) continue;; esac
    echo true
    break
done
```

With `shopt -s extglob`, you could also simply check whether `"$DIRECTORY"/!(*-suffix)` expands to one or more files:

```
shopt -s extglob   # if it's not already enabled
shopt -s nullglob  # expand to empty string if no match
for f in "$DIRECTORY"/!(*-suffix); do
   echo true for "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> if the array contains any of the elements that do not have the "-suffix" suffix

So do exactly that. Just write the loop, that iterates over one array, excluding the one with -suffix, then for each element of another array check if it "contains".

```
check_it() {
    for f in "${files[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$f" = *-suffix ]]; then continue; fi
        for d in "${directories[@]}"; do
           if [[ "$f" = "$d"/* ]]; then
               return 0
            fi
        done
    done
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test if any element of indexed array `files` has not the `-suffix` suffix, you can simply:

```sh
$ files=("dir/file1" "dir/file2" "dir/file1-suffix" "anotherdir/file")
$ if [[ "${files[*]%%*-suffix}" =~ ^\ *$ ]]; then echo no; else echo yes; fi
yes
$ files=("dir/file1-suffix" "dir/file2-suffix")
$ if [[ "${files[*]%%*-suffix}" =~ ^\ *$ ]]; then echo no; else echo yes; fi
no
```

We just substitute any `foo-suffix` element by the empty string and check if the result expanded as a single word contains only spaces.